# Consulta nativa a una tabla sin ID, en un proyecto que ya implementa Spring DATA JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

Ok trataré de explicarlo mejor, soy relativamente novato en esto de Spring JPA, y las posibilidades y configuraciones no las conozco.

Trabajo en un proyecto que tiene Spring DATA JPA, con hibernate y se conecta una base de datos Oracle 12c,   todas las tablas de dicha base están mapeadas a sus respectivas entidades y cada una tiene su repositorio que hereda de JpaRepositorio.
Ejemplo de entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tusuario")
public class TUsuario implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

ejemplo del repositorio

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import mx.com.telcel.td.spas.model.TUsuario;

public interface IUsuarioDao extends JpaRepository<TUsuario, Long>  {

}
```

El detalle es que me pidieron crear una nueva tabla ("TREGISTRO") sin ID e ir a consultar todos los registros de esa tabla, y trabajarlos.  Entiendo que no puedo crear una entidad ya que no tengo un ID, Por lo que la solución seria, según entiendo, es crear un repositorio especial y realizar un query nativo para que me traiga todos los datos.  Y es ahi donde no encuentro un ejemplo.
Si ya utilizo SPRING JPA, yo requeriria hacer la consulta con jdcb, pero

1.- Puedo ocupar el contexto de JPA, o tengo que crear otro para JDBC????
2.- Podrían darme un ejemplo en linea, la mayoría que encuentro son querys pero sobre entities,

saludos de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya tengo mis dudas aclaradas, si alguien las quiere complementar mejor pues que bueno.
1.- No, no se puede ocupar el contexto JPA, ya que la tabla no tiene ID, no se puede realizar esto, lo que se tiene que hacer es un query nativo. en mi caso se creo una interfaz DAO y una implementacion de ese DAO. En el implDAO con el entity Manager

```
@Component
public class TRegistroDAOImpl implements TRegistroDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<TRegistroVO> getTRegistros () {

        String qExtension= "";

        String sql = "SELECT "
                + "TA.ID, "
```